# How to create or save Data using RestFramework viewsets.?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I created two models that are interlinked with each other.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
class Order_Placement(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    product_price = models.FloatField()
    product_total_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    other_cost = models.FloatField()
    cost_of_sale = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    advance_payment = models.FloatField()
    remaining_payment = models.FloatField(default=0.0, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.product_total_price = self.product_price * self.product_quantity
        self.cost_of_sale = self.product_total_price + self.other_cost
        self.remaining_payment = self.cost_of_sale - self.advance_payment
        super(Order_Placement, self).save(*args, *kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.company) + ' : ' + str(self.date.date())
```

I am trying to create a view that will help me to create an object or instant of the **Order_placemen** model
But when I try to post Data it rises an error while saving with post request:
Here I created a serializer for both company and Order_placement

```
class CompanySerializer(s.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = m.Company
        fields = '__all__'

    class Order_PlacementSerializer(s.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = m.Order_Placement
            fields = '__all__'
            
        def to_representation(self, instance):
            response = super().to_representation(instance)
            response['company'] = CompanySerializer(instance.company).data
            return response
```

and I created a view for OrderPlacement using Django rest_framework.viewsets.ViewSet

```
class OrderProccessViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):
        try:
            serializer = s.Order_PlacementSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            
            dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Order Save Successfully"}
        except:
            dict_response = {"error": True, "message": "Error During Saving Data"}
        return Response(dict_response)

    def list(self, request):
        orderProccess = m.Order_Placement.objects.all()
        serializer = s.Order_PlacementSerializer(orderProccess, many=True, context={"request": request})
        response_dict = {"error": False, "message": "All  List Data", "data": serializer.data}
        return Response(response_dict)
```

When i print the prin(request.data) in **create** method its shown like this:

> <QueryDict: {'company': ['1'], 'product_quantity': ['500'],
> 'product_price': ['530'], 'other_cost': ['1000'], 'advance_payment':
> ['0']}>

Comment: May you share the full error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your **save** method, because you misspeled kwargs's argument.

You wrote:

```py
super(Order_Placement, self).save(*args, *kwargs)
```

and it should be:

```py
super(Order_Placement, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```